# ExtJs Grid into a BufferedGrid

Tags: javascript, extjs

The problem of making  a grid into an Buffered grid is not resolved.As I have applied all of the techniques being used,the problem in the grid still exists.How  can i apply the BufferedRenderer or BufferedGrid property in my already applied extjs grid which loads about 20000 records?

Comment: Make a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/).

Comment: i cant make a fiddle ,bcoz it is used in a large application but i can show what are all the properties i have used..pageSize:150,
 collapsible: true,
    selModel: {
            pruneRemoved: true
        }

Comment: Also i have designed the application in an MVC architectural form.autoLoad: true,
    buffered: true,
    remoteSort: true,
  leadingbufferzone:60,
  trailingbufferzone:60,
    proxy: {
  type: 'pagingmemory',
  reader: {
   type: 'json',
   totalProperty: 'totalCount',
   root: 'history'
  }

Comment: Can you remove grid and create it manually with bufferedrenderer plugin?

Comment: Thats the Problem constraints::I have to implement the Buffered grid Withour plugins....But i can create a Bufferedrenderer Using a plugin....

Comment: Cant we create a buffered renderer grid or an infinite scroller grid without a plugin....Is there any way possible?

Comment: you can create infinity without plugin, you just need to specify pageSize and buffered:true in your store.

Comment: Extjs 4.2.2 @Mr.George

Comment: Already did it @LightNight....The Problem is it loads all the 20000 records and then renders it page by page....What about  my autoload property?

Comment: Any solution will be appreciable....

Comment: i know about buffered store in extjs 5, but in teory is not the same of extjs 4

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can tell you to try is buffered store, try to set on your store `buffered: true;`

That allows the Store to prefetch and cache in a page cache, pages of Records, and to then satisfy loading requirements from this page cache.

To use buffered Stores, initiate the process by loading the first page. The number of rows rendered are determined automatically, and the range of pages needed to keep the cache primed for scrolling is requested and cached. Example:

```
myStore.loadPage(1); // Load page 1
```

A BufferedRenderer is instantiated which will monitor the scrolling in the grid, and refresh the view's rows from the page cache as needed. It will also pull new data into the page cache when scrolling of the view draws upon data near either end of the prefetched data.

The margins which trigger view refreshing from the prefetched data are Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer.numFromEdge, Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer.leadingBufferZone and Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer.trailingBufferZone.

The margins which trigger loading more data into the page cache are, leadingBufferZone and trailingBufferZone.

By default, only 5 pages of data (in addition to the pages which over the visible region) are cached in the page cache, with old pages being evicted from the cache as the view moves down through the dataset. This is controlled by the purgePageCount setting.

Setting this value to zero means that no pages are ever scrolled out of the page cache, and that eventually the whole dataset may become present in the page cache. This is sometimes desirable as long as datasets do not reach astronomical proportions.

I had the same problem on Extjs 5 and solved it with buffered store, but in your version of ext there isn't a specific class like in mine version, so maybe you can do it with this property

here you can read about buffered store on extjs 5: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.BufferedStore

Comment: Ext.define('DD.store.ddGridStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
 alias : 'widget.ddGridStore',
 requires:['Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy', 'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'],
 fields:[],
    autoLoad: true,
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 2,
 //forcefit:true,
    //isSortable: true,
    remoteSort: true,
 proxy: {
        type: 'pagingmemory',
        //type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
   totalProperty: 'totalCount',
   root: 'items'
        }
    }
 
});Whats the problem here?

Comment: can you post a fiddle on sencha fiddle? so we can try to solve directly the problem?

Comment: the problem could be not only in the store, so if we haven't got all the code how can we solve it?

Comment: [Extjs grid](http://jsfiddle.net/TE4ah/1187/).........This is my minature of my grid used.I have disabled pagination using pageParams:undefined and have to make the data load like bufferedrenderer..........Can you sort it out @Mr.George